# How do I fix my code for authenticating external files?

Tags: python, file, authentication

I have created an **authentication program** which **scans a directory** for files that contain the contents for which the user has requested, it has worked when it asks for the username but not when it asks fot the password. I'm not sure what to do? *It prints welcome when the Username is successful* but it *doesn't print welcome even if the password is correct*

```
userAuthen = input("What is your username? ")
path = r"C:\Users\JOSHUA\Desktop\Python stuff\usernames"
directories = os.scandir(path)
with directories as dirs:
    for entry in dirs:
        with open(entry.path,"r") as fileUser:
            contentsUser = fileUser.read()
            if contentsUser == userAuthen:
                print("Welcome!")
                break


passAuthen = input("What is your password? ")
path = r"C:\Users\JOSHUA\Desktop\Python stuff\passwords"
directories = os.scandir(path)
with directories as dirs:
    for entry in dirs:
        with open(entry.name,"r") as filePass:
            contentsPass = filePass.read()
            if contentsPass == passAuthen:
                print("Welcome!")
                break
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  It is not enough to give us a generic verbal description on unspecified inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably didn't work because when you read a file in python with `file.read()` this also includes new line separators `\n`. You don't see those separators when you open a file with a normal text editor. But they are there. When you use `file.read().splitlines()` you get an array with all lines without the `\n` separator.

Try this:

```
import os

userAuthen = input("What is your username? ")

path = r"C:\Users\JOSHUA\Desktop\Python stuff\usernames"
directories = os.scandir(path)

username_found = False
password_found = False

with directories as dirs:
    for entry in dirs:
        with open(entry.path, "r") as fileUser:
            contentsUser = fileUser.read().splitlines()
            for username in contentsUser:
                if username == userAuthen:
                    username_found = True
                    break

passAuthen = input("What is your password? ")
path = r"C:\Users\JOSHUA\Desktop\Python stuff\passwords"
directories = os.scandir(path)

with directories as dirs:
    for entry in dirs:
        with open(entry.path, "r") as filePass:
            contentsPass = filePass.read().splitlines()
            for password in contentsPass:
                if password == passAuthen:
                    password_found = True
                    break

if username_found and password_found:
    # Code if login was successful
    print("Welcome!")
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code you've given me wouldn't work and it's because my explanation for my problem was vague. The text files I'm using to authenticate the password and username both only have one line and are both in the same direectory. Also , userAuthen and passUser are inputs which are checked with the contents of the two files to see if they match,and if so, print "Welcome". Sorry about leaving my explanation vague. Hopefully this helps you?

Comment: I just put the username file and password file into two different directories. Unfortunately even if I enter the correct password, it doesn't print "welcome"

Comment: Ok. I tested my code with only one directory. I now also created a second directory for the password. I have the same problem. I'll look at it again.

Comment: I updated my answer again. It works for me now. I hope it also works for you.

Comment: Thank you, you are a god amongst men.

Comment: Glad it worked ツ. I also supplied the code if you wanted to only run code if the login was successful.